# How to use where condition for the for a selected column using subquery?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have two columns as company and product.

I use the following query to get the products matching particular string...

```
select id,(select name from company where product.cid=company.id) as 
company,name,selling_price,mrp from product where name like '$qry_string%'
```

But when i need to list products of specific company how can i do?

i tried the following but in vein

```
select id,(select name from company where product.cid=company.id) as
company,name,selling_price,mrp from product where company like '$qry_string%'
```

Help me

Comment: hope you have $qry_string properly escaped. Also I hope you would accept an answer that Worked great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do does not require a subquery, a simple join is enough. Try this:

```
select c.name, p.id, p.name, p.selling_price, p.mrp
  from company c
 inner join product p
    on c.id = p.cid
 where c.name like '$qry_string%'
```

I think the problem with the query you tried is that you cannot use fields that are the result of a subquery (in your case, "company") in the `where` clause. You might try `having` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Worked great

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT p.id, c.name AS company, p.name, p.selling_price, p.mrp FROM product p, company c WHERE p.cid=c.id AND c.name LIKE '$qry_string'
```